# Не могу выполнить упражнение по JS связанный с методами, обьектами и массивами

Tags: javascript, json

Наткнулся на упражнение в книге "Выразительный JS". Уже долго не получается его решить. Вот условия:

Используя набор [данных](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/ancestry.js), подсчитайте среднюю разницу в возрасте между матерями и их детьми (это возраст матери во время появления ребёнка). Обратите внимание – не все матери, упомянутые в наборе, присутствуют в нём.

```
var ancestry = JSON.parse(ANCESTRY_FILE);
```

При выполнении **акцент** должен быть на методах массивов.

Comment: "Не могу выполнить" - где?

Comment: В самом тесте дан предварительный ответ

Comment: Что это значит? Вы ожидаете, что Вам здесь просто код напишут?

Comment: Я новичок. У меня уже долго не получается его решить. На сайте решение не дается. Мне было интересно как же оно решается. Сам тест обычный.  В одном из глав книги "Выразительный JS"

Comment: "Мне было интересно как же оно решается." - не является уважительной причиной.

Comment: Да пожалуйста! Можете не решать. Не велика трагедия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для начала из исходного массива нужно получить массив, содержащий разницу между возрастом человека и его матери. Для этого для каждого человека находим в исходном массиве мать для текущего человека (используя фильтрацию по имени матери). Вычисляем разницу между годами рождения и возвращаем ее. Если мать не нашли, то возвращаем вместо числа с разницей null.
2. Для массива полученного на предыдущем шаге: фильтруем, отбрасывая те элементы массива, которые равны `null`.
3. Считаем сумму элементов отфильтрованного массива.
4. Делим результат предыдущего шага на длину отфильтрованного массива.

Еще одна подсказка: использовать надо следующие функции `Array`: `filter`, `map`, `reduce`.
Надеюсь, теперь вам будет понятнее, как решить задачу.